# Why is this mysql syntax wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql, web2py

```
CREATE TABLE OWLUpdates(
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
website INT, INDEX website__idx (website), FOREIGN KEY (website) REFERENCES OWLWebsite          (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
suburl VARCHAR(255),
sendtimes INT,
title VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE,
description LONGTEXT,
is_show CHAR(1),
reads INT,
degrees INT,
mtime DATETIME,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

What's the error ?? 
the web2py report :

> (1064, u"You have
>   an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'reads INT,\n
>   degrees INT,\n mtime DATETIME,\n PRIMARY KEY(id)\n) ENGINE=Inn' at
>   line 9")

Answer (score 5):

`READS` is a Reserved Keyword in MySQL. In order to use keywords, you should wrap it with backticks,

```
`READS` INT
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

But as an advise, refrain from using reserved keywords to prevent future problems.